# Efficient Method to Find the Lexographic Min of a Range of Integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting, minimize

Given two positive integers, say M and N, with M < N, what is the most efficient algorithm to find the minimum in lexicographical order of the strings of the integers from M to N represented in base ten ASCII without leading zeros? For example, for [200, 10890], the answer is '1000', for [298, 900], the answer is '298'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Comment: This expression first fails at M = 1, N = 10.  I think the second line should be "return 10^(ceil(log_10(M))".  Otherwise it doesn't work if M is a power of 10.  Then the first line should be: "if ceil(log_10(M)) <= floor(log_10(N))".

Comment: The expression as written is now: if ceil(log_10(M)) <= log_10(N) then return 10^(ceil(log_10(M))) else return M end if (just in case imgur ever removes this image...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably right in your intuition that there's a constant-time algorithm for this. You'd first find the smallest first digit, then the smallest second digit, etc.

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, that's linear time (in the number of digits in the inputs).

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right -- it is linear in the number of digits, which I guess technically makes it logarithmic for N.